# Unable to pass arguments to groovy script from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy

library identifier: 'github-project@master', retriever: modernSCM(
        github(
                apiUri: '<github_api_url>', 
                credentialsId: '<token_value>', 
                repoOwner: 'owner', 
                repository: '<repo_name>'
        )
)

groovyFile(skip_test=false)
```

This is the content of vars/groovyFile.groovy:

```
def call(skip_test=true) {
    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('Check stage') {
                when { expression { skip_test == false } }
                steps {
                    echo "Stage ran successfully."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this build in Jenkins, no matter the value passed true or false it just skips Check stage. And when I print the value if skip_test I get Null value. Can we not pass arguments to groovy in dynamic retrieval of librarires?

Ref: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#dynamic-retrieval

Comment: I don't think Groovy has default values, try `def call(boolean skip_test) {`

Comment: Yes, tried boolean and string types. But that did not help either. I still get null value when I try to access it.